# I am getting an parsing error without any code written

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code

```
Parse error on line 1:

^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got '1'
```

I get this error every type I type text, I get this error for no reason.
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxk5F.png)

Edit: I have reinstalled vscode and I no longer get this error.

Comment: I've only gotten this error in JSON, but never in TypeScript.

Comment: Are you seeing this error in other TS files too? If yes, then something is broken in the file where you configure Typescript or tsconfig.json or the like.

Comment: I'm confused; is this question related to JSON or TypeScript (because of the tags)?

Comment: I am getting this error in basically every file with no explanation

Comment: I'll try reinstall vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling *Visual Studio Code* might help resolve the error.

---

To uninstall on Windows, type in `appwiz.cpl` in the Start menu search. Then, find Visual Studio Code, right-click on it, and select *Uninstall*.

To uninstall on Mac, go to *Finder > Application*, and delete the Visual Studio Code application.

Uninstalling on Linux is a bit trickier, but you can see the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_linux).

---

To install the software, go to [*code.visualstudio.com*](https://code.visualstudio.com/).